# Combine two Observables, if two observables emit values in a time windows return combined values else emit only one value

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have two Observables, A and B. I'm looking for an operator which emits combined values 3 when both A and B emits items 1 and 2 respectively in a given time window.

If Second observable doesn't emit any value in a given time window after first Observable emitted value then we should emit single value emitted by first observable to observer but in a different way than combined value.

Subscribers should be able to differentiate between combined item or single item.

Comment: is it `Observables` or `Single`? Because you are talking about emitting 1/0 item(s) only

Comment: Both are Observables, Observable A will emits continuous items and Observable B emits items based on User actions.